# Synchronized on String.class

Tags: java, multithreading, synchronization, thread-safety, synchronized

In one of my existing Spring Java code some one has written code like below :
I am not sure why we need to synchronize String class for thread safety. Can anyone suggest?

```
public class MyTimerTask extends TimerTask{
    
    @Autowired 
    MyService service;
    
    public void run(){
        synchronized(String.class){
            service.callSomeMethod();
        }
    }   
    
}
```

Comment: Looks totally crazy to me; if they use the same locking object in other classes, then all of those will block eachother.   Typically you want to block  only those threads performing the same operation, so a good practice is to generates a unique object (eg a random string)

Comment: Yes I totally agree with you. If we use synchronized on Stiring.class then the lock will be on the String class during the period when that operation is performing. Does that mean other section of code which is using String will also be blocked as the whole String class is synchronized ? If the answer is yes then it's dangerous. Please suggest .

Comment: It'll only block other code that also synchronizes on String.class, not all code that merely uses Strings.  There probably isn't a lot of code doing that.  Still, it's a nutty thing to do in the first place.

Answer (score 3):

There is no *need* to use `String.class`. You can synchronize on any object, including any `Class` instance. Using the `String` class is a poor choice, but it would work.

The reason it's a poor choice is because (a) it's `public`—your code could interact in unexpected ways with some other part of a large program where some other programmer also decided to write `synchronized(String.class)`—But more important is (b) it's completely demented. It will make other programmers waste time trying to understand what you did and why you thought it was smart to do it.

There's maybe a third reason (c) but hard to tell without seeing more of your code. Reason (c) would be that `String.class` is a `static` instance, and if you're using that one global object to synchronize many different `MyTimerTask` instances, and if those instances do not interact with each other through shared, `static` variables, then using the one global synchronization object probably adds an un-necessary performance bottleneck.

This would be better (takes care of reasons (a) and (b)):

```java
public class MyTimerTask extends TimerTask{
    private final static Object mutex = new Object();
    ...
    public void run(){    
        synchronized(mutex){
            service.callSomeMethod();
        }    
    }   
}
```

Or, depending on how `MyTimerTask` is used, removing `static` from the declaration of `mutex` might be better still (takes care of reason (c)).